# Probability of obtaining triangle when choosing $3$ points from $3\times3$ array

Tags: probability

$9$ points are placed in a $3\times3$ array.  If $3$ points are randomly selected, what is the probability that they are the vertices of a triangle?

Comment: You sure this is the question?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: The answer depends on the bivariate distribution of points. Is it uniform?

Comment: Yes, they are uniformly distributed. 3 points each in 3 arrays.

Comment: ok I misunderstood the question. I thought the points are placed in a square $[0,1]^2$. Just to make sure by square array you mean square $n\times n$ matrix? What is $n$ then?

Comment: It is 3 times 3 matrix.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Any $3$ points would form a triangle unless they are collinear. By considering horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines, we see that there are exactly $8$ cases of collinearity. Now there are $\binom{9}{3}=84$ ways to choose $3$ points out of $9$. Hence the probability is $\frac{84-8}{84}=\frac{19}{21}$.

Comment: Does it meant that the answer is 19/27 ?

Comment: How did you get 84?